# Why is a MultiPolygon of a MultiPolygon smaller than its input?

Tags: shapely

I'm confused by the following output:

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon, mapping
>>> p1 = Polygon([(0,0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
>>> p2 = Polygon([(0,0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)])
>>> mapping(MultiPolygon([p1, p2]).convex_hull)
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)),)}
>>> mapping(MultiPolygon([MultiPolygon([p1, p2])]).convex_hull)
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)),)}
```

I assumed that MultiPolygon would return the same (not necessarily the identical) object if I give it a single MultiPolygon as input. So I expected

> (((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)),)

to instead of the returned output.

Comment: What I should have used is [`cascaded_union`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#cascading-unions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the development version of shapely, the construct `MultiPolygon([MultiPolygon([p1, p2])])` raises a `ValueError`.

To be more specific, the constructor of `MultiPolygon` seems to accept either another `MultiPolygon`, or a list of `Polygon`s. It [calls](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/a4982c7a048ea49b10ae57799c06bbbb34e82219/shapely/geometry/multipolygon.py#L62) the function `geos_multipolygon_from_polygons` which [performs](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/a4982c7a048ea49b10ae57799c06bbbb34e82219/shapely/geometry/multipolygon.py#L174) following check:

```
# This function does not accept sequences of MultiPolygons: there is
# no implicit flattening.
if isinstance(obs[0], MultiPolygon):
    raise ValueError("Sequences of multi-polygons are not valid arguments")
```

If this check (which, strictly speaking, should be probably performed on all elements of the `obs` list) is removed, the function proceeds to:

```
subs = (c_void_p * L)()

for i, ob in enumerate(obs):
    if isinstance(ob, polygon.Polygon):
        shell = ob.exterior
        holes = ob.interiors
    else:
        shell = ob[0]
        holes = ob[1]

    geom, ndims = polygon.geos_polygon_from_py(shell, holes)
    subs[i] = cast(geom, c_void_p)

return (lgeos.GEOSGeom_createCollection(6, subs, L), N)
```

Here, if an element of the `obs` list is not a `Polygon`, indexing is used to extract the `shell` and `holes`. However, for the `MultiPolygon` in your particular case, this just extracts the individual polygons `p1` and `p2`. It seems that `holes` do not affect the result of the return statement, thus the function will extract for each `MultiPolygon` only its first component.

For your example:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon, mapping
p1 = Polygon([(0,0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
p2 = Polygon([(0,0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)])

M1 = MultiPolygon([p1, p2])
M2 = MultiPolygon([M1])
print(p1) #POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))
print(M2) #MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0)))
```

If the expression `MultiPolygon([MultiPolygon([p1, p2])])` is modified to `MultiPolygon(MultiPolygon([p1, p2]))`, the resulting convex hull is as expected.